# How to calculate index from array

Tags: c++, math, vector

I would like to calculate which index holds the data for X/Y coordinate inside a vector containing bitmap data.

```
int receiveBitmapCoordinateIndex(int x, int y, int bmp_width, int bmp_height) {
    int final = 0;

    // Y
    final += bmp_width * (bmp_height - y);

    // X
    final += x - 1;

    return final;
    //((((bmp_height)-(y)) * bmp_width) + x);
}
int main()
{   
    std::cout <<"Should be: 249 999 func:" << receiveBitmapCoordinateIndex(1, 1, 500, 500) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Should be: 249 998 func:" << receiveBitmapCoordinateIndex(2, 1, 500, 500) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Should be: 0 func: " << receiveBitmapCoordinateIndex(500, 500, 500, 500) << "\n";
system("pause");
}
```

The vector would have the size of 500 * 500 = 250 000, but the first index would be at 0 and the last one at 249 999.

The bitmap data is upside down, meaning that X:1 Y:1 would be 249 999, what am I doing wrong with my math?

I tried changing the math around, but I can't seem to get it working, honestly not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Math in the code seems fine, it's when you are calculating it yourself that the problems start. X:1 Y:1 should be 249 500, it's only the Y axis that is reversed.

Comment: I recommend using 0-based indices. Otherwise you quickly get confused with C++ arrays/vectors. In case of 0-based incides you could simply write `size_t receiveBitmapCoordinateIndex(size_t x, size_t y, size_t bmp_width, size_t bmp_height) { return x + (bmp_height - 1 - y) * bmp_width; }` Subtracting 1 from every occurance of `x`/`y` yields your formulae though. Btw: I wouldn't recommend using keywords like `final` as identifiers, even if you're allowed to do this. My suggestion: use `result`.

Comment: Thanks @fabian, now I see what the issue was, thanks to your example & explanation!

Do you know a great course where I could learn how to write better code and get familiar with C++?

Comment: @Lenarolla Depends on your programming experience, and which level of C++ experience you want to get and which language standard you expect to be available to you. https://www.learncpp.com/ seems to be a decent point to start, but if you want to write high quality code, the best thing that could happen to you after working though a tutorial like this is an experienced programmer reviewing a mid-sized part of code you wrote (and iterated on until you were happy with the quality) and get feedback on areas to improve in. The question is basicelly just a math problem though, not a C++ one.

Comment: (Also remember that asking for recommendataions on books, courses, etc. is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here, and will get questions closed, and may get your comment flagged)

Comment: To elaborate on John's comment: if you have a flattened WxH 2D pixel array where the y coordinate is flipped, then the first sequence of W numbers (index `0...W-1`), represents the coordinates from `(x=0, y=H-1)` through to `(x=W-1, y=H-1)` (assuming zero-based offsetting, which is the C++ default convention). Everything at `W...(2W-1)` represents `(x=0, y=H-2)` through `(x=W-1, y=H-2)`, and so on, with the last sequence of N numbers being `(x=0, y=0)` through `(x=W-1, y=0)`. So: update the statement that calculates the flattened index given the x, y, W, and H values.

Comment: The code won’t build (as shown), because `final` is a keyword. Please show a M**W**E.

Comment: *"what am I doing wrong with my math?"* -- Why do you think something is wrong with your math? (Your question is missing the output of your program.)

Comment: Much love to all of you, thanks for being so helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For bitmap data, adjust the function to subtract `y` from `bmp_height + 1` and keep `x` unchanged.

`Pixel (1,1)` corresponds to the array's end, and (width, height) to its start.

```
int receiveBitmapCoordinateIndex(int x, int y, int bmp_width, int bmp_height) {
    int final = 0;

    // Y
    //final += bmp_width * (bmp_height - y);
    final += bmp_width * (bmp_height + 1 - y); //<---- here

    // X
    //final += x - 1;
    final += x; //<---- here

    // Subtracting one because array indexing starts from 0
    final -= 1;

    return final;
}

int main()
{   
    std::cout << "Should be: 249 999 func: " << receiveBitmapCoordinateIndex(1, 1, 500, 500) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Should be: 249 998 func: " << receiveBitmapCoordinateIndex(2, 1, 500, 500) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Should be: 0 func: " << receiveBitmapCoordinateIndex(500, 500, 500, 500) << "\n";
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Thanks @knoxgon for also displaying which details I have done wrong.